# Reading existing height of a div prevents code from working

Tags: jquery, css

To switch the height of a div I use this code, which works very fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trg = $("#hauptTextInhaltReduziert"), // The target container
    preHeight = 420;
  trg.css("height", preHeight); // Set the initial height on page load  
  $(".aufklappen").on("click", function() {
    var curHeight = trg.height();

    if (preHeight == curHeight) {
      var xHeight = "auto";
      $(this).text("-");
    } else {
      var xHeight = preHeight;
      $(this).text("+");
    }

    var trgHeight = trg.css("height", xHeight).height();
    trg.height(curHeight).stop().animate({
      height: trgHeight
    }, 600, function() {
      trg.css("height", xHeight);
    });
  });
});
```

Because this should only come to work in mobile versions of the site, where the initial height of the div is set to 420px, I changed the line #3 to this:

```
preHeight = $("#hauptTextInhaltReduziert").css("height"); // The initial height
```

But now, the code doesn't work any more.

So what is wrong with this line?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using $(this) in the context of no element. There is no $(this) for jQuery to get the height of. Set it to an existing element.

Comment: `this` refers to the document.  Hence you are getting the error

Comment: Thanks you wrxsti. I have just become aware and edited my post (see the code above), while you have been answering it. Sorry for that. Now there is no more error. BUT the code still doesn't work.

Comment: The `css` function will return a value with `px` inside. Like `100px`. But `height()` return a numeral value. You can't compare or set them with `height()` again.

Comment: @eisbehr: thanks, this helped. I changed the line where the heights are compared to `var curHeight = trg.css("height");` now the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix up `css("height")` and `height()` because css use the extensionsions, like `px`. So use one method for all. Best usability is to keep it numerals, for better working with, like compare ...

```
$(function() {
    var trg = $("#hauptTextInhaltReduziert"),
        preHeight = 420; 

    trg.height(preHeight);

    $(".aufklappen").on("click", function() {
        var curHeight = trg.height();

        if (preHeight == curHeight) {
            var xHeight = "auto";
            $(this).text("-");
        } else {
            var xHeight = preHeight;
            $(this).text("+");
        }

        var trgHeight = trg.height(xHeight).height();

        trg.height(curHeight).stop().animate({
            height: trgHeight
        }, 600, function() {
            trg.height(xHeight);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value with `.css( propertyName , value )` such that the value can be directly set in css. In this case, you are setting the value 420 to the height. In css, this would result in `height: 420`, which is not working.

My suggestion is that you change that to `preHeight = '420px'`. To make the rest work as well (since `.height()` returns a numeral value), you should change that part as well.

The following code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trg = $("#hauptTextInhaltReduziert"), // The target container
    preHeight = '420px';
  trg.css("height", preHeight); // Set the initial height on page load  
  $(".aufklappen").on("click", function() {
    var curHeight = trg.height();

    if (preHeight == (curHeight + 'px') ) {
      var xHeight = "auto";
      $(this).text("-");
    } else {
      var xHeight = preHeight;
      $(this).text("+");
    }

    var trgHeight = trg.css("height", xHeight).height();
    trgHeight = trgHeight + 'px';
    trg.height(curHeight).stop().animate({
      height: trgHeight
    }, 600, function() {
      trg.css("height", xHeight);
    });
  });
});
```

This should also fix the other problems.

Comment: No, this will not work. There are more changes to do. Like here: `if(preHeight == curHeight)`.

Comment: That's true, I will change the answer.